# Boot Loop CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, boot-loop, sony-xperia-z

I am installing **Cyanogen Mod 10.2.1** on my **Sony Xperia Z** (yuga).

I followed all instructions exactly given on Installing [CM Mod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_yuga).

But after following the steps and clicking on **`Reboot system now`** in **CWM-based Recovery**, my device got stuck into a boot loop.

I tried all possible solution that I found but none worked -

> Tried command `adb reboot recovery` and reflashing rom
>
> Tried wiping cache partitions and dalvik cache
>
> Tried reading this [general help article](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info)

Please help in figuring out how to exit this loop and boot into **Cyanogen Mod** or **Android**. Please remember that I have Xperia Z and I cannot take out the batteries.

Comment: This usually happens for 1 of 2 reasons. 1: Are you sure you installed the correct CyanogenMod specifically for your device? 2: Did you wipe user data and cache before (or after) installing CyanogenMod via CWM? Step #7 is the important one in the instructions that you posted.

Comment: Yes I installed the specific version made for my device and I also followed the step 7 exactly as given...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem created by a failed installation of CyanogenMod.

Please make sure you have read the notes on the CM-Wiki:

> **Note:**
>
> On 2011 models, the kernel will not update when flashed in recovery, so the kernel must be >updated via fastboot every time you flash a new build of CyanogenMod.

As far as I know you should be able to exit the loop by long pressing the power button until the screen goes black.

Also I suggest you install CM11 as Android 4.4 has far more support by the community than 4.1-4.3.

Before installing any new rom I would consider installing a stock rom to flash all possibly missing files and then begin to flash everything again (recovery, rom, kernel etc. in that order)